# Not able to ssh to port 443 on a Amazon ec2 server

Tags: linux, security, ssh, amazon-ec2, firewall

I am running ssh on Amazon EC2 (linux) machine on Port 443.

Yet i am unable to ssh it, as i am behind a firewall.

When i do
 
    http:// host:443

Following message is displayed:
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3

That means ssh is clearly listening on port 443, and the port is even reachable (via browser).
But yet when i do ssh from my desktop command-line (or putty), it just doesn't work.

Is it that firewall is examining packets and blocking it?
Any ideas?

Comment: Test `ssh` using telnet ,or test your `SSH` on another computer.Don't you need specific `MTU` ?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -p 443 -v host`? This will show a detail logs and might tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked!
The putty also required proxy entries :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing `ssh -p 443 host`?  Sorry to state te obvious... but sometimes the obvious is what eludes us.